# How Thread.Start() runs run method of the Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that `Thread` implements `Runnable`. When you call `start()` from Thread, I hope it calls the `run()` method of the `Runnable` from which it has been implemented.

Thread's one of the parameterized constructor accepts `Runnable` object.
i.e. `Thread(Runnable target)`.

Now I want to know, How `run()` method of target is being called from the `start()` method of the Thread?

Do they have the reference of the `Runnable` inside Thread class?

It would be helpful if anybody can post the definition of the `start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. If you look at the Thread.java class of the standard library, you'll see this line:

```
/* What will be run. */
private Runnable target;
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#154

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. :)

Comment: @Venkatesh: also the jdk download includes source code for the jdk libraries.

Comment: You could pad out this answer by showing how `thread.run()` invokes `target` if `target` is set.  Some moderators here don't like link-only answers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - the Thread object keeps a reference to the Runnable, and inside its `run()` method, calls the Runnable's `run()` method.

The `start()` method doesn't get involved with the runnable; its purpose is to request that the Thread be scheduled to execute.

You can also override the Thread's `run()` method, but that is a poor design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at source code of `start()` method in [Thread class](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java/?v=source)

```
 /**
     * Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine
     * calls the <code>run</code> method of this thread.
     * <p>
     * The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the
     * current thread (which returns from the call to the
     * <code>start</code> method) and the other thread (which executes its
     * <code>run</code> method).
     * <p>
     * It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
     * In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
     * execution.
     *
     * @exception  IllegalThreadStateException  if the thread was already
     *               started.
     * @see        #run()
     * @see        #stop()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        /**
         * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
         * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
         * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
         *
         * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
         */
        if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        group.add(this);
        start0();
        if (stopBeforeStart) {
            stop0(throwableFromStop);
        }
    }

    private native void start0();
```

In above code, you can't see invocation to `run()` method.

`private native void start0()` is responsible for calling `run()` method. JVM executes this native method.